# How to sort values arraylist<hashmap<string,string>>

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have ArrayList with three values(Strings) but second is number and i want to sor numeric from 0 to e.g. 100. In this time it's sort 1,10,2,21,5 etc. In output i want to have 1,2,5,10,21.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray devices = jsonObj.getJSONArray("list");

                for (int i = 0; i < devices.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = devices.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String known = c.getString("known");
                    String description = c.getString("description");
                    String controllerId = c.getString("controllerId");


                    JSONObject frequencySurvey = c.getJSONObject("frequencySurvey");
                    if (frequencySurvey.has("5000")) {
                        JSONObject fivezero = frequencySurvey.getJSONObject("5000");

                        String timestamp = fivezero.getString("timestamp");
                        String clients = fivezero.getString("clients");
                        String enabled = fivezero.getString("enabled");

                        HashMap<String, String> device = new HashMap<>();

                        device.put("id", id);
                        device.put("name", name);
                        device.put("enabled", enabled);
                        device.put("clients", clients);

                        DevicesList.add(device);

                    }


ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Devices_5_0.this, DevicesList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "name","clients","enabled"},
                new int[]{R.id.name,R.id.clients, enabled});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And I use this sort but it sort by strings:

```
class SortValues implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        HashMap<String, String> test1 = (HashMap<String, String>) obj1;
        HashMap<String, String> test2 = (HashMap<String, String>) obj2;
        return test1.get("clients").compareTo(test2.get("clients"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a numeric string into integer

```
class SortValues implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        HashMap<String, String> test1 = (HashMap<String, String>) obj1;
        HashMap<String, String> test2 = (HashMap<String, String>) obj2;
        return new Integer(test1.get("clients"))
            .compareTo(new Integer(test2.get("clients")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If clients value is your number value this will work:

```
class SortValues implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        HashMap<String, String> test1 = (HashMap<String, String>) obj1;
        HashMap<String, String> test2 = (HashMap<String, String>) obj2;
        Long firstClients = Long.valueOf(test1.get("clients"));
        Long secondClients = Long.valueOf(test2.get("clients"));
        return firstClients.compareTo(secondClients);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Collections.sort(arrayList,new ArrayListHashMapComparator());

 public class ArrayListHashMapComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String,String>> {

        @Override
        public int compare(HashMap<String, String> lhs, HashMap<String, String> rhs) {

            try {
                return lhs.get(lhs.keySet()).compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.get(rhs.keySet()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

above code is sort all hashmap values in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code for sorting arraylist values.

```
public ArrayList<NotificationValues> mAllNotificationList = new ArrayList<NotificationValues>();
Collections.sort(mAllNotificationList, new Comparator<NotificationValues>() {
@Override
public int compare(NotificationValues lhs, NotificationValues rhs) {
    return lhs.getTimestamp().compareTo(rhs.getTimestamp());
}});
```